# Proving the Horner Function (Polynomial Evaluation)

Tags: algorithm

I completed exercise 1-8 in *The Algorithm Design Manual*, Second Edition, by Steven S. Skiena:

[image]

Is it convincing?

Comment: If the algorithm is formulated using recursion, yes. For the iterative version try to come up with a loop invariant.

Comment: Belongs on math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Is there a bug here I'm missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Typically in induction proofs you separate steps from each other. The induction step is too implicit for my taste. I'd do it like this:

**1)** for n = 1 horner([a0], x) = a0

**2)** horner([a0,...,a(n+1)], x) = x * horner([a1,...,a(n+1)], x) + a0 = x * horner([b0,...,bn], x) + a0, where bn = a(n+1)

**3)** Thus having horner for n, horner for n+1 can be calculated with 2)

Your proof is fine, but as I've said - induction step should be clearly accented - how solution for n+1 follows from solution for n (m in your case), in a separate proof step.

Answer (score 2):

#### Using loop invariant

- This is a proof using loop invariant by [Daniel Schelpher](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3520344/563958)

#### Using Induction

1. **Induction Hypothesis**

[image: Induction Hypothesis]

2. **Base case**

[image: Base case]

3. **Induction step**

[image: Induction step (a)]
[image: Induction step (b)]

4. **Conclusion**

[image: Conclusion]

Answer (score 1):

The way I remember this is to write P(x) as:

```
P(x) = a_0 + x(a_1 + x(a_2 + ... + x(a_{n-1} + x a_n)) ... ))
```

from which the for loop directly follows.